# Merge header to have only one header in file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```scala
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    object APP{

      def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit = {
        val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
        val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
        FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null)
        // the "true" setting deletes the source files once they are merged into the new output
      }

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://dc-bir-cdb01;databaseName=dbapp;integratedSecurity=true";
        val driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        val BusinessDate = "2019-02-28"
        val destination = "src/main/resources/out/"
        val filename = s"Example@$BusinessDate.csv.gz"
        val outputFileName = destination + "/temp_" + filename
        val mergedFileName = destination + "/merged_" + filename
        val mergeFindGlob = outputFileName


        val spark = SparkSession.
          builder.master("local[*]")
          //.config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "100")
          .appName("Application Big Data")
          .getOrCreate()
        val query = s"""(SELECT a,b,c From table') tmp """.stripMargin

        val responseWithSelectedColumns = spark
          .read
          .format("jdbc")
          .option("url", url)
          .option("driver", driver)
          .option("dbtable", query)
          .load()

        print("TOTAL: "+responseWithSelectedColumns.count())

        responseWithSelectedColumns
          .coalesce(1) //So just a single part- file will be created
          .repartition(10)
          .write.mode("overwrite")
          .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .option("charset", "UTF8")
          .option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false") //Avoid creating of crc files
          .option("header", "true") //Write the header

          .save(outputFileName)
        merge(mergeFindGlob, mergedFileName)
        responseWithSelectedColumns.unpersist()

        spark.stop()
      }
    }
```

The code above produces a file with multiple headers.

How should I modify the code to have only one header in a file?

Comment: How about simply removing `.repartition(10)`?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are trying to generate csv files with only one header for all of them. One straightforward solution would be to use `coalesce(1)` and to remove the `repartition(10)` that you introduced. The problem with that is that all the data goes to one partition. It can be very slow or worse, throw an OOM error. Yet (if it works) you get one big file with one header.

To keep taking advantage of spark's parallelism a, you can write the header separately like this (assuming that we have a dataframe `df`)

```
val output = "hdfs:///...path.../output.csv"
val merged_output = "hdfs:///...path.../merged_output.csv"

import spark.implicits._
// Let's build the header
val header = responseWithSelectedColumns
    .schema.fieldNames.reduceLeft(_+","+_)

// Let's write the data
responseWithSelectedColumns.write.csv(output)

// Let's write the header without spark
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
val f = hdfs.create(new Path(output + "/header"))
f.write(header.getBytes)
f.close()

// Let's merge everything into one file
FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(output), hdfs, new Path(merged_output),
                                false,hadoopConfig, null)
```

Note also that spark 2.x supports writing csv out of the box. This is what I used instead of databricks' library which makes things slightly more verbose.

Comment: Can you help me provide the full code solution from my code snippet.?

Comment: I checked my code and for some reason, the header does not always appear first. Let me modify my answer and add more details.